# Error assigning position to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to assign a value to an array position as follows:

```
//Javascript file
var totales = new Array();

$('.total').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");//value of id => "empresa_bundle_revision_capitulos_1_requisitos_1_articulos_1_total"
    var arrayids = id.split("_");
    if(totales[arrayids[4]] == undefined){
            totales[arrayids[4]] = new Array();
    }
}
```

In a console.log i get this how totales value:

```
[undefined, []]
```

This should return something like:

```
[[]]
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Add the html with `.total` class as well.

Comment: what does `arrayids[4]` yeilds ?

Comment: arrayids[4] return "1"

Comment: I think the problem might be on "1" is a string, not a number. Try casting it to number with `Number.parseInt()`

Comment: If you set an entry on index `1`, then what do you expect index `0` to contain? → `undefined` It can't simply not exist.

Comment: Oh, @deceze thanks, this is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to achieve setting an entry on index 1 as @deceze pointed. using if you want to assign new values, then add for `index` 0 :

```
   if(totales[arrayids[4]]==undefined){
     totales.push([]);
     console.log(totales);
     totales[arrayids[4]] = new Array();
     console.log(totales);
    }
```